# Why do i get parse error in Haskell trying to read from file?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am trying to read primes from file and I got an error at read, saying there is no parse

Here is my code

```
primFileRead1 = do
    temp <- readFile "prim.txt"
    let ls = read temp :: [Int]
    putStrLn $ show ls
    let n = length ls
    putStr "number of primes: "
    putStrLn $ show n
```

And here is the output:
"*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

The file is not empty, what did I wrong?

Comment: Can you share a (part) of the file? Likely the format in the file is not correct.

Comment: Unless the file has the format `[1, 2, 3]`, including brackets and commas, `read` will crash.

Comment: I used the wrong format in the file, thank you all :))

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @chi in a comment, the `read` command is intended to parse data formatted as Haskell code, so a list of integers would need to be formatted `[1, 2, 3]`.